# Implementation Python interpreter over micro controller?

Tags: python

I would like to implement python interpreter on GPP micro controller(Lets consider PIC microcontroller by Microcohip), similar to [nodeMCU](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html) . The [micropython](https://micropython.org/) isn't supporting all kind of microcontrollers, so which interpreter can we use for it, or If I get source code then how can I modify it for make it working on micro controllers. Any suggestions? Please edit it further if you understand what exact I want to do.